# How to define time variable in quarterly panel dataset

Tags: datetime, stata

I have a quarterly panel dataset, I want to define the time variable (`t`) and I proceed this code on stata:

```
gen t = quarterly(quarter, "QY")
format t %tq 
xtset country t
```

I get the following error:

> repeated time values within panel

`quarter` is a string variable (copied from excel) that present time variable of my panel data of 16 countries for the period spans 2005q1 until 2015q4.

Comment: What you show looks reasonable, if indeed `quarter` converts correctly to a SIF quarterly date. You should use the `duplicates` command to identify combinations of country and t that are repeated, and try to understand what that tells you about your data. For example `duplicates example country t`. See `help duplicates` for more information on the use of this command.

Comment: @William Lisowski gives excellent advice, but there is nothing here that we can check. This is an FAQ http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/repeated-time-values/